# If SESSION destroy then update data in database

Tags: php, session, chat

I am creating a PHP chat plugin for that I want when created session are destroy update a column. As I am using this :

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id=$_GET['id'];
}


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","chat");
$sql="UPDATE signin SET status='offline' WHERE id=".$id;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


unset($_SESSION['name']);
unset($_SESSION['email']);
unset($_SESSION['id']);

header("location: index.php?logout");
```

That is working fine, when user click on logout button. But if the user close browser or whole system, the update is not working while session are destroy, any body please help to solve this problem.

Comment: Sessions are deleted after a period by php automatically. I think there is no way to to do that. Unless you write your own session management and store session data into the database.

Comment: try using manually `session_destroy()`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with sessions.

You need to set cookies for that -> like Remember me function. example:

```
setcookies('name', $_SESSION['name'], time()+3600); // 3600s
```